# Rails 4 Passing Parameters From One Controller to Another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a clients controller and and payments controller. When a client is created I want to automatically redirect to a new payment form and also pass the client id to payments.

In the clients model:

```
has_many :payments
```

In the payments model:

```
belongs_to :client
```

In clients controller:

```
def create
@client = Client.new(client_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @client.save
    format.html { redirect_to new_payment_url (:client_id => @client.id) }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @client }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

In payments controller

```
  def new
    @payment = Payment.new
    @client = Client.where(:id => params[:client_id])
  end
```

When I create a client it redirects to the new payments form but the client id does not get passed. When I try to save that payment I get an error saying client can't be blank.

I know that you can't pass an object to another controller without first saving it but my understanding was:
i) I'm not trying to pass through the entire client object, just the id and
ii) doesn't @client.save save the object to the DB then execute and following lines of code?

I'm a little confused about all of this so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
format.html { redirect_to new_payment_url (:client_id => @client.id) }
```

to look like this

```
format.html { redirect_to new_payment_url(:client_id => @client.id) }
```

Comment: Hi, I've made that change but it hasn't solved the problem. The client id is still not getting passed.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `client_id` in the URL? Try adding a `puts "#{new_payment_url(:client_id => @client.id)}"` right after the `@client.save` and check from the rails console.

Comment: The url is literally ipaddress:3000/payments ... there's definitely no client_id being sent

Comment: What happens if you write `app.new_payment_url(:client_id => Client.first.id)` in `rails console`?

Comment: Client Load (5.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> "http://www.example.com/payments/new?client_id=3"

Comment: Try adding that puts statement in the controller and debug from there.

Comment: That puts statement is there, right after @client.save as you said.

Comment: Check in the rails server log for the output of that.

Comment: All I'm seeing in the log is the sql command that comes up in the console as well. Sorry if seem a bit dense about this but debugging rails apps is something I'm kind of new at. It probably shows :)

Comment: It probably is there, you just can't see it since there is so much text.Use this trick `puts "=" * 50 + " #{new_payment_url(:client_id => @client.id)}"`. You should see a wall of `=` followed by the url

Comment: I think there might be a deeper problem with my app because there is no output from that puts statement in the logs. There should be 50 = signs right? That's definitely not showing up. I tried ctrl+F as well to search the document for a pattern of consecutive "="

Comment: Is it possible that @client.save is not being executed?

Comment: Maybe the save is executed but fails, try adding a similar puts after the `else`

Comment: The puts statement was still not giving me any output so I tried logger.info in the payments create action and refreshed my browser page. All the fields that I fill out on the form are being 'seen' and their values are being printed out but there is no client_id.

Comment: Turned out I had a typo. This answer went a long way towards helping. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only instantiate a new Client via the line

```
@client = Client.new(client_params)
```

By that @client will not have an id until the record is saved.

Since i assume you want to create a record and then further process that data actually persist the record by calling `create` instead of `new`.

```
@client = Client.create(client_params)
```

Comment: Sorry for the necromancy. I just realized how old this question actually was.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
format.html { redirect_to new_payment_url (:client_id => @client.id) }
```

to look like this:

```
format.html { redirect_to new_payment_path(:client_id => @client.id) }
```

If the above does not work, then pass the 'path' string to redirect_to like these
`"/payment/new?client_id=#{@client.id}"`.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those work. :client_id is an attribute belonging to payments, could there be an issue with the way I've called it in the clients controller?

Comment: If possible, can you provide me link for app?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. I have figured out though that client_id is being passed to new payment form but when I save the new payment form the client_id doesn't save.

Comment: then assign hidden field the value of client id